# HP Pavilion does nothing but beep three times on startup

Tags: boot, bios

White performing some sort of HP update, my HP Pavilion P6214Y PC computer froze and now will not turn back on.

My computer does nothing when I try to start it up except beep three times.

Nothing appears on the monitor, and no lights turn on on the mouse or the keyboard. This is not a memory issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, look into the manual what 3 beeps mean.

Comment: 3 short beeps Unable to start flashing (such as when missing a utility or BIOS image)
This is from the HP Support website...but no solution given.

Comment: @peter it looks like he already saw that question - there's a deleted answer by him saying he had the same problem. @user84487, are you sure it's not a memory problem? Did you try reseating the modules?

Comment: How do you know it's not a memory problem? Sure sounds like it could be a possibility to me. Other things to try:  Reseat *everything* (memory, boards, plugs, etc.) and make sure everything is snug. Try again; if you do get in, run diagnostics. If that doesn't work: remove any extension boards such as graphics (but only if you have on-board to fallback to), and see if one of those has gone belly-up.

Comment: I think it is a coincidence that the update just happened to occur at the same time as the beeping. It sounds like a memory issue to me. What makes you say it is not? What makes you so sure? I googled your model, and everyone with 3 beeps talks about RAM or other heat-related MB failure. 3 beeps is traditionally RAM problems: http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Comment: I did find one place that said that on an Insyde BIOS, 3 beeps was no video device found.

Comment: My motherboard is a Pegatron M2N78-LA with integrated graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce 9100), how would I test it to see if that is the problem...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From HP:](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01884928&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4006029#N99)

> **The computer starts, but makes beeping sounds**
>
> Beep sounds typically occur when a keyboard key is stuck, a memory DIMM or hard drive cable is not seated properly, or a component on the motherboard has failed. Disconnect the mouse and keyboard, and then restart the computer. If the beeping noise stops, repair or replace those devices.
>
> To find out more information about a specific beep pattern, see [BIOS Beep Codes and Error Message Descriptions](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07107&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=4006029).

Also, test your hard drive and memory: [How to test RAM and HDD (Hard Drive)](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/td-p/301638)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07107&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=4006029&tmp_track_link=ot_search#N46) for the meanings of beep codes of HP BIOS types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what BIOS vendor HP uses, but you should check it [here](http://www.bioscentral.com/).

It could be any number of issues depending on the POST beeps during startup.

Comment: FYI recent HP laptops use an Insyde BIOS.

Comment: I tried swapping out the RAM and that didn't work...I tried changing the jumpers to reset the CMOS and that didn't work...according to the HP website the three beeps:

Comment: 3 short beeps Unable to start flashing (such as when missing a utility or BIOS image)...but HP does not state what to do and since my machine is out of warranty it looks like I am out of luck with them...

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your memory?

Do a hard reset, disconnect power cord and hold power button in for 30 seconds, connect power cord back and try power up.

Do a cmos reset, disconnect Power cord, open the case and remove the cmos battery (note polarity) leave cmos battery out for 15 Minutes, while the battery is out re-seat your memory modules, reinsert cmos battery after 15 Minutes, connect power cord, power up, If you get the HP bios splash screen Immediately enter the bios and set the date and time Before Windows loads, use F10 to do this.

Documents I found for your model

[HP Bios Beep codes](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07107&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=4006029)

[HP No boot document](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01884928&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4006029#N57)

Comment: As an update...I pulled the battery for at least an hour and still the same three beeps...I tried moving the jumpers...and still the three beeps...I removed the four RAM boards and reinserted them...and still the same three beeps...tonight I will try to starting it up with only two RAM boards to see if that helps...I really appreciate everyone's input and assistance...thank you

Comment: I tried switching out all the RAM boards and using different combinations of the four boards...and all I get are three beeps...ugh

Comment: What year was this PC purchased new?

Comment: Just took it to a local computer repair shop and the motherboard is fried...around $300 to fix it...the thing only cost $500 on Black Friday in 2009...